# How Keycloak uses AdminURL to achieve single sign-out

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak

aims:
Use keycloak as a certification center to integrate multiple independent systems, and each system has its own certification method.
Similar to the implementation of CAS, there is a local conversation between the user and each system, and a global conversation between the user and the keycloak, in order to minimize the change cost.

Question:
Independent systems A and B. When A logs out, it calls the keycloak logout interface to exit the global session. How does keycloak notify B to let it exit the local session?
At present, I found that keycloak has an AdminURL configuration. I understand it as a callback request when logging out, but no request is sent to the target callback?

The document here is too brief, how to use this AdminUrl?

[admin url configuration instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwoDJ.png)
[admin url configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ2lq.png)